# How to concat return of two axios get calls, Nuxt.js Sitemap

Tags: javascript, function, concatenation, nuxt.js, sitemap

Hey guys hope u are doing well :) I have this situation that I dont know how to solve, so Im trying to fill nuxt.js sitemap of my dynamic websites, so when I had only one call all worked fine and I got what I needed in sitemap.xml but when I add other one I guess I need to concat results, but I dont know how...

```
 sitemap: {
    routes: async () => {
      let { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/articles");
      return data.map(v => `${v.slug}`)
    }
  },

I need to add same stuff just with diferent api "http://localhost:1337/faq/slug"
```

And with one result of both api calls, I need to fill sitempa.xml :)

Comment: Did my answer helped you somehow ?

Comment: yes a lot thanks for ur time, I dont have jet option to give u upwotes Im sorry :( but when I lvl up my stackoverflow acc I will come back and do it :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you can do this

```js
sitemap: {
  routes: async () => {
    let { data: articlesData } = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/articles");
    const articlesArray = articlesData.map(v => `${v.slug}`)
    let { data: slugData } = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/faq/slug");
    const slugsArray = slugData.map(v => `${v.slug}`)
    return [...articlesArray, ...slugsArray]
  }
},
```

This should work fine if you want to join 2 arrays. Otherwise, give us an example of what is the end structure we need here.

PS: `articlesData` and `slugData` are renamed on the fly here to avoid redefining the same variable and keep things clean.

Comment: Yep that is what I was looking for actualy I was trying with concat but no luck xD thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my project.

To solve this problem I did make one request for my api. In Api I created a method in which I processed all requests.

```
sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 1440,
    hostname: process.env.SITEURL,
    routes: async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(`${process.env.BACKADDR}/getSiteMapRoutes`);
        return data.routers
    }
},
```